# How to iterate all properties/fields in bean/Object, includes reference Object/Bean

Tags: java, spring, apache, reflection

[background]

```java
public class All {

     Private List<CClass> listc;

     private BClass b;

     @customerAnnotation
     Private String all1;
}

public class B {

     @customerAnnotation
     String A;

     String B;

     @customerAnnotation
     Class C
     ...
}

public class C {

     @customerAnnotation
     String d;

     String e;
}

public list<Field> myProcess(All bean) throws BusinessException;
```

question：

1. How to get all fields that it has marked by `@CustomerAnnotation`, includes reference object field?
2. `[field.getAnnotation(customerAnnotation.class)]`, it just can get the first top, but I want to get second, third...
3. Is there any Framework or Utils can do that or help me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this one

```
Class aClass = All.class;
Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation) annotation;
        System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());

    }
}
```